# Determine if a class in python is a metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

Is there a way in python to determine if a class object is a metaclass?

I know that you could check using the equality operator. 
    metaclass == type

But that wouldn't cover for user defined metaclasses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test if the object is a subclass of `type`:

```
issubclass(MetaClass, type)
```

This returns `True` for all metaclasses, including `type` itself.

Demo:

```
>>> class Meta(type): pass
...
>>> class Foo(object): pass
...
>>> issubclass(Meta, type)
True
>>> issubclass(Foo, type)
False
```

Answer (score 4):

Most metaclasses are `type` subclasses (`issubclass(metaklass, type)`) **but not all**:

```
>>> def logging_meta(name, bases, namespace, **kwd):
...     print(name, bases, namespace, kwds)
...     return type(name, bases, namespace, **kwds)
... 
>>> class C(metaclass=logging_meta):
...     a = 1
... 
C () {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'C', 'a': 1} {}
>>> issubclass(logging_meta, type)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

i.e., the answer is "any callable e.g., a class with a `__call__()` method that accepts the same arguments as `type()` and returns a class object will do":

```
>>> class C(metaclass=lambda *a: lambda *a: None): pass
... 
>>> C()
>>> type(C)
<class 'function'>
```

Comment: Is this valid python 3 code? I thought python 3 got rid of the metaclass argument in the constructor.

Comment: @BenHoff: yes. It is Python 3 code. Python 3 uses `metaclass` in the `class`  statement (it is not a constructor). Python 2 uses `__metaclass__` attribute (on the class or module).

Comment: This is not quite an answer, but does raise an important point: what you *specify* as the metaclass isn't necessarily a class; it just has to be a callable that *returns* an object with the same API as a `type` object.

Comment: @chepner: I've added the explicit answer.